# Stored procedure not working in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created the following stored procedure but not working as expected.....Some error line 3

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mytest.sp_insert_request $$ CREATE DEFINER=developer@127.0.0.1 PROCEDURE sp_insert_request(@RequestID varchar(250) = null, @Status varchar(45)= null,@Status_message varchar(9180)= null,@time_of_post varchar(9180) = null,@time_of_start varchar(9180)= null,@time_of_completion varchar(9180)= null) BEGIN

INSERT INTO request ( RequestID, Status, Status_message, time_of_post, time_of_start,time_of_completion) VALUES ( @RequestID, @Status,@Status_message,@time_of_post,@time_of_start,@time_of_completion );

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: you need to highlight your lines of code and then click on the "code" button (010 101) on the editor toolbar, or press Ctrl-K on your keyboard, to nicely format and syntax highlight code (including SQL)

Answer (score 2):

The insert ends with ; but you defined DELIMETER $$